# Switching Keyboard Layout on Macbook on Lion

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

Is it still possible to switch from the default (Macbook UK) keyboard to the US layout in Lion? Everything I've read says there should be an international option in System Preferences, but there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences -> Language & Text -> Input Sources

[image]

Comment: its not there lol

Comment: Confirmed on Lion, thanks. @XAleXOwnZX, you can download custom layouts for any not listed. What are you looking for?

Comment: They are just missing on the screenshot. At the right hand side of the input sources list there should be a scroll bar.

Comment: patrrix, us english or english (us) isn't there lol

Comment: see http://d.pr/i/Svjf, same for UK english